# Run c# .exe file without installing it (Include DLLs)

Tags: c#

I am using c# Desktop base application in  Visual Studio 2008 which is zip maker so i want to make .exe file must run without installing it. So can anyone help me to do this?

I want to include all .dll file in that exe and want to run it without installing it.

Answer (score 2):

ILMerge allows you to package your dependent DLLs into your .exe file.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By default VS makes .exe file goto your project debug folder and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Build!

The Exe is created in the `"\bin\Debug"` Folder.

Copy the Exe From the `"\bin\Debug"` Folder.

If more Dll's are present use [IlMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to pack all the dll and exe to one file.

An alternative to IlMerge is [.NETZ](http://madebits.com/netz/)

Use the new exe without installation!

Comment: That will only work if there are no dependant DLLs required. ie - multiple projects in the c# solution

Comment: Then the Dll Files will also be present in the same directory and Ilmerge should be used. he first didn't mention that there was Dll's present. Answer Updated!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to ILMerge, you can package you DLLs as an embedded resource and load them on demand.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx